# C# WInForms TextBox DataBinding refresh TetxtBox.Text if bindings property change

Tags: c#, winforms

```
class Class1
{
   public string val {get;set;}
}
Class1 cl;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
cl = new Class1();
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",cl,"val",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,);
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", cl, "val", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }    


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl.val += "11";
        }
```

I change value in textBox1, at textBox2 value changes immediatly too. 
  If I click button, bindings value cl.val changed from code, but both textBox value stay unchanged.
 
How to refresh data on textbox form if cl.val change from code?
 
 
PS: if after row  
 
cl.val += "11";  - add 
 
textBox1.Text = cl.val; 
 
then value refresh at both textBoxs
 
why is that?

Comment: Class1 must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to notify the controls of its changes.

Comment: I need refresh value at all tetxBox at the form by command that look like form.Refresh()... I don't wont implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my class, it generated by Entity Framework dataBase First.Thank you.

Comment: Then show code that has more to do with the problem. We can only comment on the problem the code has you show.

Comment: @ВладимирВ, if you don't want implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in class `Class1` then you cannot use DataBinding. Create viewmodel class (MVVM pattern) which contains reference to Class1 and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 3):

In order to make data binding work when data source property is changed by a code, the data source (`Class1` in your case) must provide some sort of a property change notification. The possible choices are events called `PropertyNameChanged` where `PropertyName` is the name of the property for which the change notification applies, or more general approach is to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example using the second approach. Since the C# auto properties cannot be used anymore, people usually create a base class to reduce repetitive boilerplate code needed like this

```
public abstract class BindableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected static bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
class Class1 : BindableObject
{
    private string _val;
    public string val
    {
        get { return _val; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _val, value); }
    }
}
```

Once you do this, everything will work as expected.

If as you said your class is auto generated by EF, then you need to create a wrapper class (usually referred as ViewModel) to be used for UI data binding. In general, DTOs, Entities etc. classes are not for direct use in the UI.

**Update** While all the above is the right way to go, for the sake of completeness, here is a quick and dirty approach.

Helper function:

```
public static class DataBindingUtils
{
    public static void RefreshBindings(this BindingContext context, object dataSource)
    {
        foreach (var binding in context[dataSource].Bindings.Cast<Binding>())
            binding.ReadValue();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cl.val += "11";
    BindingContext.RefreshBindings(cl);
}
```

Comment: dirty approach is good for me :). I"ll be  angry and terrible coder :). Thank Ivan...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cl.val+="11";
textBox1.ResetBindings();
textBox2.ResetBindings();
```

**Update**

The fact is that when you change the class value, you must notify the UI that the underlying data has changed, so you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your class. Define your class Class1 like this and try it:

```
class Class1:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _val;
        public string val
        {
            get
            {
                return this._val;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._val != value)
                {
                    this._val = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**

As Ivan and me has explained, the way to do it is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. But if you want a dirty way of doing it,you could clear databindings and add them again, something like:

```
cl.val += "11";

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
       if (c is TextBox)
       {
            c.DataBindings.Clear();
            c.DataBindings.Add("Text", cl, "val", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        }
 }
```

Comment: This kills the whole idea of the data binding

Comment: don't work..  After this - seems the bindings is lost... , if I am changing value at TextBox1 it is no changing at textBox2...

Comment: Thank, but I would like to refresh value at all tetxBox at the form by  command look like form.Refresh()... I don't wont implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my class, it generated by Entity Framework dataBase First.

Comment: In update 2 I explain a dirty way of doing it..but i won't recomend it and i will go Ivan Stoev or mine way

Comment: Ok, thank you. other way, like update <br>          cl.val += "11";

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
       if (c is TextBox)
       {
             TextBox.Text=cl.val;
        }
 }