# Winform textbox binding c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

I have a struct that looks like the following

```
 public struct t
 {
     public string x { get; set; }
     public string y;
 }
```

I'm trying to bind a Text box to it so the value in the text box get set to x;  I'm trying to set this up via the Winform designer like so
[image]

Is this even possible?  The project I'm working on has to be a Winform and cannot be migrated to WPF.  Is there a way to directly link the value in a text box to a structure property or a variable via the winform designer?  The real project has hundreds of text boxes and I'm looking for a shortcut to that doesn't involve writing hundreds of lines of code.  I've been digging around on here for a while now and I can't find a good solution that fits my needs.  They all involve doing this manually.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you are looking for [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bind-wf-controls-with-the-bindingsource)

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996655/c-sharp-winforms-textbox-databinding-refresh-tetxtbox-text-if-bindings-property) a question that has the answer on how to properly do it. Secondly by code it's not true it would take hundreds of lines. At most 20 lines.

Comment: you can simply do it using `System.Reflection` library. it can be even easier if you set your textboxes names like variables/structures/properties they should display.

Comment: @MaciejS. `System.Reflection` and "simply" don't get along well very often.

Comment: **(1)** By sharing an struct as example, are you asking about data-binding to `Struct` rather than `Class`? **(2)** By sharing a field as example, are you asking about data-binding to `Field` rather than `Property`?